# extract specific character from list using python

Tags: python

Suppose I have a list of keywords from webpage as:

`samp=["scientific research","analytics","companies"........and so on]`

now I want to extract only those character which consist word "analytics" using python.

Comment: `[k for k in samp if "analytics" in k]`

Comment: `filter(lambda x: 'analytics' in x, samp)`

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will help you:

```
for items in samp:
    if 'analytics' in items:
           print(items)    #or you can append them to another list
```

Comment: this will extract item that is exactly `analytics`, but OP needs all items which contains the `analytics` as a substring. You had to use `if 'analytics in items'`.

Comment: Ya you are right...i thought he wants to extract exactly analytics.

Answer (score 0):

Use list comprehension!

```
print [s for s in samp if 'analytics' in s.lower()]
```

This should get all the items in the list with 'analytics' in it!
Hope it helps!